# Trying to return list of child pages for a template

Tags: page-template, child-pages, pages

I am trying to return a list of Child pages that belong to a template.  I then show these on a different page.

I have a Store, that has store child pages.  On a products page (not related to the store or its children) I want to show the first three child pages of a store page in that language ( i have multiple Store pages in different languages, but not all of them have children i.e. the Spanish store has no child store items yet, whereas the Dutch has many items in its store).

This is what i have, but it returns every page - not just Store children

```
  <?php // Pull in child pages from Store the landing page
    $storetemplate = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template', 'meta_value' => 'templates/store-landing.php' ) );
    $pages = get_pages('child_of='.$storetemplate->ID.'&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=desc'); 

    ?>

  <ul class="u-flexbox store-features">
    <?php // For each child page pull in it's field data
    $count = 0;
    foreach($pages as $page): ?>

      <? $post = $page->post_parent; ?>       
        <li class="jsEqualHeights-2 store--item">
          <a href="<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID) ?>">
            <?php $img = get_field('store_details_overview_image', $page->ID); ?>
            <img src="<?= $img['url']?>" alt="<?= $img['alt']?>" width="<?= $img['width']?>" height="<?= $img['height']?>" class="jsEqualHeights-3">                
            <p><?php echo $page->post_title ?></p>
            <p class="store-items--category"><?php the_field('store_details_categories', $page->ID); ?></p>
          </a>          
        </li>        

    <?php endforeach; ?>
      <li class="jsEqualHeights-2 store--item store--item-all">
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID) ?>"> 
          <p class="jsEqualHeights-3 u-flexbox store--item-all-blurb">See more integrations, add-ons and products in the Store</p>
          <p class="store--item-all-readmore">Click to see more</p>
        </a>          
      </li>   
  </ul>
```